# How to fix datetime error when extending HIT in mturk using boto3

Tags: datetime, boto3, mechanicalturk

Attempting to extend expiration on a list of hits per [API instructions](https://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/mturk.html#MTurk.Client.update_expiration_for_hit)

```
for hit_id in expired_hit_list:
    response = client.update_expiration_for_hit(
        HITId=hit_id,
        ExpireAt=datetime(2017, 4, 9, 19, 9, 41, tzinfo=tzlocal())
    )
```

getting error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-e0764e20a54b> in <module>()
      2     response = client.update_expiration_for_hit(
      3         HITId=hit_id,
----> 4         ExpireAt=datetime(2017, 4, 9, 19, 9, 41, tzinfo=tzlocal())
      5     )

NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

I also tried datetime.datetime and dateTime and also just removing it.

```
ExpireAt=(2017, 4, 9, 19, 9, 41, tzinfo=tzlocal())
```

nothing working.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's just an issue with my Python setup, nothing to do with boto3

```
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzlocal
```